# AdMob site URL for app that can be downloaded from many places

Tags: android, admob

If Android app with AdMob banner has site URL `market://details?id=<com.example.app>` Will it work for requests and clicks from installations made not from the Google Play? I have app posted on 1mobile and some forums, so I want installations from there to use AdMob too. Should I make it `http://` instead of `market://`?

Comment: What do you mean by site URL ?

Comment: In AdMob Sites and Apps are the same things, so for every app you need to provide it's URL. It's called "site URL" and it can be changed in "manage settings" menu in AdMob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you app will trigger admob data, it will use the api key that admob gave you, nothing else. And this is not related to the way your app has been downloaded and installed.

So, yes, admob will work. It will display ads in your app, whichever market it has been installed from.

If your question is : I wanna promote my app using admob with a market URL to encourage people to install it, then no, it will only work for devices and countries that support the market. There are some devices that don't support it at all, like archos devices for instance.

So, if you plan distributing your app this way, it would be much better to provide a free URL, not linked to the android market and allow users to see that page, and download the apk either via the market or direct download or alternative markets.